# Lost Wi-Fi after running USB to Ethernet driver

Tags: macos, wifi, ethernet

I recently bought a USB to Ethernet dongle, and I ran the package script and restarted the computer, only to find that I had the infamous ‘Wi-Fi: no hardware installed’ issue. I've tried:

1. Reset NVRAM
2. Reset SMC
3. Moved and renamed `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist`
4. Ran the AHT, and entered recovery mode.

On attempt 3, after it didn't work, I undid it.
On attempt 4, I found no hardware issues, and when I clicked the link, I could connect to Wi-Fi.

MacBook Pro 12,1, Insignia USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet adapter

Answer (score 2):

I decided to brute-force my way to a solution. I first ran the AHT by holding down "d" while booting up. Then I held down `Command R` when booting up, and reinstalled the OS. That worked.